# rgb2lab in MatLab and OpenCV provide different results

Tags: matlab, opencv

I converted a RGB-image both in MatLab and OpenCV to the Lab-colorspace to do some color manipulation in Lab-space. In MatLab I get good results, but in OpenCV the result image is messy.

I checked the results of the conversion rgb2lab for the RGB-value [0 255 0] in MatLab and OpenCV, the results are the same. But when converting back (lab2rgb) I get different results in MatLab and OpenCV. Any idea why?

The Lab-value is [88 10 68]:

- in Matlab I get [255 212 81] as RGB-value by using lab2srgb
- in OpenCV I get [255 166 23] by using CV_Lab2RGB

Comment: Did you make sure to use the correct value ranges & data type?

Comment: In which range are the Lab-values in MatLab and OpenCV? I couldn't find anything about itin order. Only that in order to compare Lab-values from OpenCV with MatLab I have to multiply L with (100/255), subtract a and b with 128 respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there was an error in OpenCV 1.x, because after installing OpenCV 2.1 yesterday, my algorithm is working fine and I get results I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

default image format in OpenCV is BGR. You may be assuming its in RGB order...